# A regular expression to check if a column contains another column value

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, algorithm, relational-database

I have a specific scenarios which is stated like below :
Table `T1` contains `Name` and `status`. Table `T2` contains column `Name_status`. `status` will have values of `pass` and `fail`. `Name_status` should have values like `<Name>_<status>ed`.

Can we think of a regular expression which would fetch all the values in `<Name>_<status>ed` format.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: 1) Where exactly need the values be fetched from, and 2) how should the result of the fetchings look like?

Comment: The value should come from `T2`. The result should look like `James_Passed` if the status is `Pass`.

Comment: Are the results from T2 linked to entries in T1 by means of a foreign key or any other reference device?

Comment: I dont want to hard code the name value in the given format while applying the SQL query.

Comment: NO foreign key associated. That is the necessity of using regex here.

Comment: The example you gave `James_passed`. Would the name `james` come from `tb1`

Comment: So the relational data bears no relation. What a silly database! Do you need an SQL query for this, or in what language do you expect us to write this regexp?

Comment: I think of a query like this : `select Name_status from T2 where Name_status like '<Name>_<status>ed' and (Name,status) in (select Name, status from t1); `  If it is a fisible scenario , then please help.

Comment: Ritesh check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this

```
 SELECT *
   FROM T1, T2
  WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE(T2.Name_Status, '^(.+?)_(.+?)ed$', '\1') = T1.name   
    AND REGEXP_REPLACE(T2.Name_Status, '^(.+?)_(.+?)ed$', '\2') = T1.status
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work out fine

```
   SELECT name_status 

FROM(SELECT * FROM tbl1, tbl2 WHERE tbl2.name_status 

REGEXP concat(tbl1.name,"_",tbl1.status)) as temp
```

Comment: What SQL dialect do you use?

Comment: Hi @James : In oracle the `tbl2.name_status REGEXP` comes out to be `ORA-00920:invalid relation operator`

Comment: @diziaq mysql dialect